# Keyboard filter driver not responsing

Tags: keyboard, driver, wdk

I've written a simple keyboard filter driver (MyKbdFilter), registered it in registry and added to HLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\UpperFilters MyKbdFilter. Now I have: "kbdclass MyKbdFilter". So, when building a new device stack for a keyboard I get MyKbdFilter->kdbclass->kbHid->HidUsb. When I'm plugging a keyboard, I see that DriverEntry, AddDevice, DispatchThru and DispatchPNP are called. But keyboard is not responding. On key stroke neither DispatchRead nor other functions are called.
Here is my code:

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN DRIVER_OBJECT* pDriverObject, IN UNICODE_STRING* pRegPath) {    
    int i;
    NTSTATUS status;


    for (i = 0; i <= IRP_MJ_MAXIMUM_FUNCTION; i++) {
        pDriverObject->MajorFunction[i] = DispatchThru;
    }

    pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_READ] = DispatchRead;

    pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_POWER] = DispatchPower;
    pDriverObject->MajorFunction[IRP_MJ_PNP] = DispatchPNP;

    pDriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadDriver;

    pDriverObject->DriverExtension->AddDevice = AddDevice;

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

NTSTATUS AddDevice(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject, IN PDEVICE_OBJECT pTargetDeviceObject){
    PDEVICE_OBJECT pSourceDeviceObject, pDeviceObject;
    PDEVICE_EXTENSION pDeviceExtension;
    NTSTATUS status;

    status = IoCreateDevice(pDriverObject, sizeof(DEVICE_EXTENSION), NULL, FILE_DEVICE_KEYBOARD, 0, FALSE, &pSourceDeviceObject);

    pDeviceExtension = (PDEVICE_EXTENSION) pSourceDeviceObject->DeviceExtension;

    pDeviceObject = IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack(pSourceDeviceObject, pTargetDeviceObject);

    pDeviceExtension->pLowerDeviceObject = pTargetDeviceObject;

    pSourceDeviceObject->Flags = pDeviceObject->Flags & (DO_BUFFERED_IO | DO_POWER_PAGABLE | DO_DIRECT_IO);
    pSourceDeviceObject->Flags = pDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;

    return status;
}

NTSTATUS DispatchThru(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject, IN PIRP pIrp) {
    IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(pIrp);

    return IoCallDriver(((PDEVICE_EXTENSION) pDeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->pLowerDeviceObject ,pIrp);    
}

NTSTATUS DispatchRead(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT pDeviceObject, IN PIRP pIrp) {
    IoSkipCurrentIrpStackLocation(pIrp);

    return IoCallDriver(((PDEVICE_EXTENSION) pDeviceObject->DeviceExtension)->pLowerDeviceObject ,pIrp);    
}
```

EDIT: I'm using windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pDeviceObject = IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStack(pSourceDeviceObject, pTargetDeviceObject);
pDeviceExtension->pLowerDeviceObject = pTargetDeviceObject;
```

this is error :
need by sense `pDeviceExtension->pLowerDeviceObject = pDeviceObject;`

but really correct code

```
IoAttachDeviceToDeviceStackSafe(pSourceDeviceObject, pTargetDeviceObject, &pDeviceExtension->pLowerDeviceObject);
```

this is main point, which just visible.

```
pSourceDeviceObject->Flags = pDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;
```

else one error - need:

```
pSourceDeviceObject->Flags &= ~DO_DEVICE_INITIALIZING;
```

Comment: Thank you! I don't know why I've set lowerdevice to be higher)